# How to disable Log4j configuration from external Maven dependency?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, log4j2

I have Spring Boot application with Log4j2 XML configuration file placed in `resources/log4j2.xml`. One external library I use is installed via Maven dependency and have own logging configuration in `logback.xml`.It seems that this file overwrites my Log4J2 configuration and logging is now controlled by this config file.

I'm getting logger instance (`org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger`) this way:

`private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Foo.class);`

**Q: How can I disable Log4J configuration from external library?**

Edit 1: Added Maven dependencies related to Log4j2

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
    <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-log4j2</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: A `logback.xml` file will configure Logback, not Log4J. You should probably not use both. Nowadays most people use SLF4J, Logback or Log4J as backing implementation and redirect everything else to SLF4J to keep a single logging solution. What are your maven dependencies?

Comment: @DidierL I added Maven dependencies related to Log4j.

Comment: I think best would be to run `mvn dependency:tree` to check if you have anything else that brings it in. What is the library that has `logback.xml`? I guess it must depend on Logback… It would be good to provide a [mre].

Comment: I agree with Didier: if both `logback-classic` and `log4j-core` are available at runtime, Spring Boot chooses the former.

Comment: Nice. If your prepare a GitHub repository with the spring boot and library, It would be easy and interesting to find a solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shortly:

The problem in your case is Spring try to use slf4j first (which is part of `logback-classic`) and Spring get it, due to logback exists in your classpath at runtime. Exluding the resource file from dependency is not a trivial.

Detailed:

Spring-JCL under hood try to init logging system by searching classes in classloader in next order:

1. try to load Log4j (if slf4j available load slf4j bridge)
2. try to load Log4j
3. try to load slf4j
4. load java util logging

Full logic is available here: [github spring source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/main/spring-jcl/src/main/java/org/apache/commons/logging/LogAdapter.java)

After that Spring boot start to config logger (using `LoggingApplicationListener`). In this phase  Spring Boot configure logger using config file and available logger from classpath.
In your case one of the dependencies uses `logback-classic` as a dependency and as a result it is available for springboot in runtime, that is why it uses `logback-classic`.

**There are a few possible ways how to solve your problem:**

1. Migrate to `logback-classic` and use it in your project (it is preferable)
2. If it is hard to change `log4j2` to `logback-classic`, you can support both of them (for your code config from `log4j2.xml` will be used and `logback.xml` will be used for spring). It is necessary to add `logging.config` configuration to `application.properties` with path to your custom `logback.xml` - [doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/howto-logging.html)
3. If you want to use `log4j2` as a logger for springboot itself, it is necessary to exclude `logback-classic` from your dependency(it can lead to problems with dependency, which use it)